# How to reference a specific row in an Excel table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to reference a specific row in an excel table, but I get "Application Defined or Object defined error". Here's the line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchedDeals").Cells(i, "A") = _
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data"). _
    Range("Table_ExternalData_1[[" & iStartingRow & "],[TransID]]")
```

where `iStartingRow` contains the row number to reference, and `TransID` represents the column. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you are missing a quotation mark for one.

Comment: That's just in the example. The code does have the quoteation mark. I just corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of addressing the table through a range, try to address the table (in VBA it's a `ListObject`):

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchedDeals").Cells(i, "A") = _
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data"). _
    ListObjects("Table_ExternalData_1")._
    ListColumns("TransID").DataBodyRange(iStartingRow)
```

Comment: @Chuff: I discovered them a while back - and now basically do everything with tables! The only caveat imo is that the `DataBodyRange` is `Nothing` when the table is blank (which kind of makes sense, but causes errors if you want to determine size, etc.), so some code is a bit more bloated. But having a small table wrapper class also sorted this problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
Sub sample()

    iStartingRow = 2
    Set d = Sheets("Data").ListObjects("Table_ExternalData_1")
    Worksheets("MatchedDeals").Cells(i, "A")  = d.ListRows(1).Range.Cells(iStartingRow, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: @Lukasz You may try this one.